# Swift / iOS / expected member name following '.'

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to create a backend for an app using the follow tutorial (in Swift!):

https://backendless.com/feature-2-registering-app-users-with-the-user-registration-api/#

But in the `registerUser()` function it tells me: **expected member name following '.'** at the line `Types.try({ () -> Void in`

*Everything else works fine.* Even if I delete this function and execute the `registerUserAsync()`, the user will be created. So It is not an framework importation issue.

Is it possible, that it is an Swift1/2 Issue? Since the code is in Swift1 (`println(...)`)

Any help is appreciated

The Code:

```
//  ViewController.swift
//  F2RegisteredUsersSwift

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let APP_ID = "YOUR-APP-ID"
    let SECRET_KEY = "YOUR-SECRET-KEY"
    let VERSION_NUM = "v1"

    var backendless = Backendless.sharedInstance()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        backendless.initApp(APP_ID, secret:SECRET_KEY, version:VERSION_NUM)

        registerUser()
        registerUserAsync()
    }

    func registerUser() {

        Types.try({ () -> Void in

            var user = BackendlessUser()
            user.email = "spiday@backendless.com"
            user.password = "greeng0blin"
            user.setProperty("phoneNumber", object:"214-555-1212")

            var registeredUser = self.backendless.userService.registering(user)
            println("User has been registered (SYNC): \(registeredUser)")
            },

            catch: { (exception) -> Void in
                println("Server reported an error: \(exception as Fault)")
            })
    }

    func registerUserAsync() {

        var user = BackendlessUser()
        user.email = "green.goblin@backendless.com"
        user.password = "sp1day"
        user.setProperty("phoneNumber", object:"214-555-1212")

        backendless.userService.registering(user,
            response: { (var registeredUser : BackendlessUser!) -> () in
                println("User has been registered (ASYNC): \(registeredUser)")
            },
            error: { (var fault : Fault!) -> () in
                println("Server reported an error: \(fault)")
            }
        )
    }

}
```

Comment: Try to remove "." at the end

Comment: Do you mean the "." between "Types" and "try"? That's obviously not working and I don't see another "." at the registerUser() function

Comment: At the end of your expressrion

Comment: As Che said, change Types.try({ () -> Void in. to Types.try({ () -> Void in

Comment: Okay. I see. My Bad. "Types.try({ () -> Void in" is the line. The last dot is just ending the sentence

Comment: I've edited it. I'm sorry

Comment: `Types.try({ () -> Void in` looks perfectly fine to me... Why don't you convert it to Swift 2?

Comment: Okay so I gess my problem is, that I don't know how to convert Swift 1 into Swift 2. But thank you. This just answered my question. The Issue is, that the code is Swift1. Thank you.

Comment: @DavidSeek Edit->Convert->To Latest Swift Syntax… My first proposition was wrong ;) It will propose to replace "try" and "catch" with "\`try\`" and "\`catch\`"

Comment: Okay. That deleted the error messages. I now have some other Issues within the Tests and UITests Folder but I don't care at the moment because it's a test project anyway. If you want, you cant rewrite your answer as an "answer" so I can check and upvote you. Thank you

Comment: One quick question. Will this (Types. ` try `) gives the block the same functionality? Looks a bit unfamiliar.

Comment: Should work. Coz it linked with '+(void)try:(void(^)())try catch:(void(^)(id exception))catch' in Types.h file now.

Comment: @Che please repost again as answer, so I can give you upvote and check it as solved with your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should update this project to Swift 2.0. You can do it via

> Edit->Convert->To Latest Swift Syntax…

This will update your code and replace **try**, **catch** with **'try'**, **'catch'**
I think it will be done because

> "try" is a reserved word (used for error handling) in Swift 2.

Answer (score 3):

"try" is a reserved word (used for error handling) in Swift 2. If you have a method or function named "try" in your Swift 1 code, you better rename it.